# Bridge Mode with fail open

Tags: networking, reverse-proxy, failover, bridge

I have a GNU/Linux server running an HTTP reverse proxy (Nginx). The upstream server is well-know (IP address on a subnet).

What I would like to "guarantee" is that in case reverse proxy goes down, due to crash or other unpredicted occurrence, HTTP traffic is bridged/forwarded to the upstream.

Is it possible to accomplish this at the Operating System level? If the Application level does not "take" the request, it is forwarded to the upstream by the operating system.

I am aware of the balancers solution but first I want to discard this scenario.

**UPDATE** Reverse proxy server is inside a private network quite often preceded by a WAF which does not use DNS but the IP address of the reverse proxy server.

Thanks in advance for your feedback/help.

Answer (score 0):

You could use DNS failover

One way to do it: http://www.dnsmadeeasy.com/services/dnsfailover/

Comment: My reverse proxy is inside a private network quite often preceded by a WAF which does not use DNS but the IP address itself.